# Asking for ignored files to be pushed in GitHub

Tags: git, github, github-desktop

I have repository in GitHub.com. For push and pull I use a visual tool Github Desktop. Recently I have created a repository in Github.com to store .NET Core API project. I created a git ignore file indicating which files should not prompt to push. The git ignore file is given below:

```
Source/.vs/*
Source/Libraries/Common/bin/*
Source/Libraries/Common/obj/*
Source/Libraries/Data/bin/*
Source/Libraries/Data/obj/*
Source/Libraries/Domains/bin/*
Source/Libraries/Domains/obj/*
Source/Libraries/Services/bin/*
Source/Libraries/Services/obj/*
```

But each time I build the project in Visual Studio 2019 the below files are prompting to push though they are included in git ignore not to prompt. The prompted file lists are given below:

```
Source/Libraries/Common/bin/Debug/netcoreapp3.1/Common.dll
Source/Libraries/Common/bin/Debug/netcoreapp3.1/Common.dll
Source/Libraries/Common/bin/Debug/netcoreapp3.1/Common.pdb
Source/Libraries/Common/obj/Debug/netcoreapp3.1/Common.csproj.FileListAbsolute.txt
Source/Libraries/Common/obj/Debug/netcoreapp3.1/Common.csprojAssemblyReference.cache
Source/Libraries/Common/obj/Debug/netcoreapp3.1/Common.dll
Source/Libraries/Common/obj/Debug/netcoreapp3.1/Common.pdb
Source/Libraries/Data/bin/Debug/netcoreapp3.1/Data.dll
Source/Libraries/Data/bin/Debug/netcoreapp3.1/Data.pdb
Source/Libraries/Data/obj/Debug/netcoreapp3.1/Data.csproj.FileListAbsolute.txt
Source/Libraries/Data/obj/Debug/netcoreapp3.1/Data.csprojAssemblyReference.cache
Source/Libraries/Data/obj/Debug/netcoreapp3.1/Data.dll
Source/Libraries/Data/obj/Debug/netcoreapp3.1/Data.pdb
Source/Libraries/Domains/obj/Debug/netcoreapp3.1/Domains.csproj.FileListAbsolute.txt
Source/Libraries/Domains/obj/Debug/netcoreapp3.1/Domains.csprojAssemblyReference.cache
Source/Libraries/Services/obj/Debug/netcoreapp3.1/Services.csproj.FileListAbsolute.txt
Source/Libraries/Services/obj/Debug/netcoreapp3.1/Services.csprojAssemblyReference.cache
Source/Web/obj/Debug/netcoreapp3.1/Web.csproj.FileListAbsolute.txt
Source/Web/obj/Debug/netcoreapp3.1/Web.csprojAssemblyReference.cache
Source/.vs/CashFlow/v16/.suo
Source/.vs/CashFlow/v16/.suo
Source/Libraries/Common/bin/Debug/netcoreapp3.1/Common.dll
Source/Libraries/Common/bin/Debug/netcoreapp3.1/Common.pdb
Source/Libraries/Common/obj/Debug/netcoreapp3.1/Common.csproj.FileListAbsolute.txt
Source/Libraries/Common/obj/Debug/netcoreapp3.1/Common.csprojAssemblyReference.cache
Source/Libraries/Common/obj/Debug/netcoreapp3.1/Common.dll
Source/Libraries/Common/obj/Debug/netcoreapp3.1/Common.pdb
Source/Libraries/Data/bin/Debug/netcoreapp3.1/Data.dll
Source/Libraries/Data/bin/Debug/netcoreapp3.1/Data.pdb
Source/Libraries/Data/obj/Debug/netcoreapp3.1/Data.csproj.FileListAbsolute.txt
Source/Libraries/Data/obj/Debug/netcoreapp3.1/Data.csprojAssemblyReference.cache
Source/Libraries/Data/obj/Debug/netcoreapp3.1/Data.dll
Source/Libraries/Data/obj/Debug/netcoreapp3.1/Data.pdb
Source/Libraries/Domains/obj/Debug/netcoreapp3.1/Domains.csproj.FileListAbsolute.txt
Source/Libraries/Domains/obj/Debug/netcoreapp3.1/Domains.csprojAssemblyReference.cache
Source/Libraries/Services/obj/Debug/netcoreapp3.1/Services.csproj.FileListAbsolute.txt
Source/Libraries/Services/obj/Debug/netcoreapp3.1/Services.csprojAssemblyReference.cache
Source/Web/obj/Debug/netcoreapp3.1/Web.csprojAssemblyReference.cache
```

The place of the gitignore file is given below:
[image]

Can anyone help me to solve this problem.

Comment: Where is the "git ignore" file and what is its filename?

Comment: gitignore file is in the root folder

Comment: The root folder of your computer? And what is its filename?

Comment: the file name is : .gitignore

Comment: And it is in the root folder of what?

Comment: I have edited the question. file path is given in the image

Comment: Okay. And have you added these files, for which you are prompted, to a commit before? What is the output of `git status`?

Comment: I am using GitHub Desktop Tool to push and pull. Not using command line

Comment: Can you please use the command line for a moment to debug this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You haven't added all subdirectories. For example, your .gitignore should look like this.

```
Source/.vs/*
Source/Libraries/Common/bin/*
Source/Libraries/Common/obj/*
Source/Libraries/Data/bin/*
Source/Libraries/Data/obj/*
Source/Libraries/Domains/bin/*
Source/Libraries/Domains/obj/*
Source/Libraries/Services/bin/*
Source/Libraries/Services/obj/*
# new lines:
Source/Libraries/Common/bin/Debug/*
Source/Libraries/Common/bin/Debug/netcoreapp3.1/*
Source/Libraries/Common/obj/Debug/*
Source/Libraries/Common/obj/Debug/netcoreapp3.1/*
Source/Libraries/Data/bin/Debug/*
Source/Libraries/Data/bin/Debug/netcoreapp3.1/*
```

And add all the other folders that the build shows it's adding, just not the files as I started to do. **Adding everything using an asterisk does not add subdirectories.**